# HDMI - how to turn on display and switch input

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a TV which has 4 HDMI inputs. I have a Chromecast and a Nintendo Switch connected, and I've noticed that when I turn any of them on (for example try to cast something from my phone), the TV turns on and automatically switches to the correct input.
I'm wondering how that works, **is there something in the HDMI specification which is used as an interrupt to turn on the TV ?**

I would eventually like to be able to do the same thing from my computer (so that when I plug it in I can turn the TV on and switch it to the right input without having to use the TV remote).
But most of all I'd love to know how these devices do it, and know what protocol / signal is used ??

I've read about DDC (with `ddccontrol` and `ddcutil`) and CEC (`libcec`) but I'm not sure that my TV supports it. Also, these seems too complex and not portable enough to be the technology that it used by a Chromecast, but maybe I'm wrong ?

Anyway, I'd love to learn more but it seems like a complicated topic with lots of different technologies. Any help would be greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: start at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI .... also https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+cec&ia=web

Comment: I believe the TV has to support CEC to be HDMI compliant.  Note that CEC is a hardware standard with a software API, and it won't help you if your computer device doesn't support it.  For instance, the raspberry Pi supports it.   I don't know if the Switch supports it.  Through CEC the video source can both turn on the TV and request input be switched to it.  The Pi CEC API can actually list other devices and request the TV switch to any other device too.

Comment: Thanks, I had a good read :) however as you suggested I think my laptop doesn't have hardware support for CEC. Isn't there another mecanism to simply turn a display on ?